# Are there any legal, legit Windows XP *.dll repositories?

Tags: windows-xp, dll

I support a variety of legitimately licensed Windows XP machines in different locations, some of which have occasionally missing .dll files at boot, which causes them to complain loudly.

Other than the Windows XP install disc(s), which aren't necessarily available at every location unless I travel there with them or ship them to the location, are there any other legitimate sources of these *.dll files?

The reason that not all sites have install discs are due to volume licensing, since only one set of discs was provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your locations networked together on a VPN? If so, image the install disc, mount it on a virtual drive on a server, and allow all your PCs access to map that drive. It will be accessible from all your locations that can access the server.

Comment: Sadly, all locations are not on the same VPN.

Comment: I want to suggest checking MSDN or something but I am not sure if they have any of that up there.